Azure Pipeline: Can not access Credentials Helper Store due to missing tty
on my target Ubuntu machine I installed docker, docker compose and pass (as credentials store).
So this is what my ~/.docker/config.json file looks like:
{
        "auths": {
                "whatever.azurecr.io": {}
        },
        "credsStore": "pass"
}

The problem is, that my set GPG Key is password protected.
If I ssh into the host and wanted to pull the newest docker image via
docker compose up --force-recreate -d

, I would get this error:
exit status 1, out: `exit status 2: gpg: public key decryption failed: No such file or directory

If in the same session I execute this command, it works great:
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)

Now my problem is that I need to execute the docker compose command automatically via an Azure pipeline. This is the step that I'm struggling with:
- bash: |
    export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
    echo "GPG_TTY: $GPG_TTY"
    echo "Starting all Docker Containers..."
    docker compose up --force-recreate -d

The first echo command outputs
GPG_TTY: not a tty

And then I get the same "No such file..." error shown above.
What am I missing here?
Thanks a lot

What kind of agent are you using in Azure Pipeline? Microsoft-hosted agent or self-hosted agent.

Self hosted - Ubuntu 24.04

Ok, I don't know whether this is the smoothest solution, but at least I am now able to execute a headless Azure Pipeline Deployment to my target server.
Before I call the docker compose command, I execute this:
gpg --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase "$(GPG_KEY_PASSPHRASE)" --decrypt $(GPG_PASSWORD_STORE_PATH)
where $(GPG_PASSWORD_STORE_PATH) represents the path to the .gpg file.
Then my docker compose command works.
